# Number Format Exception while reading from a text file

Tags: java

Here I'm reading text file which contains a integer in each line and I'm printing all the integers which appeared more than once.

As you can see I used Hash Map and I assigned integers as Key and number of occurrence of number  as value.

Here I'm getting Number Format Exception here. Can anyone help me with this?

```
package fileread;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> lines = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/kiran/Desktop/text.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String str;

        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

            Integer intObj = Integer.valueOf(str);
            if (lines.containsKey(intObj)) {
                int x = 0;
                x = lines.get(intObj);
                if (x == 2) {
                    System.out.println(intObj);
                }
                lines.put(intObj, x++);

            } else {

                lines.put(intObj, 1);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The exception message will show what it was attempting to parse as an integer.

Comment: Is the `DataInputStream` necessary?  Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild yeah, that DataInputStream seems unnecessary.  You should be able to pass `fstream` directly into the `BufferedReader` constructor.

Comment: @sgusc The `InputStreamReader` is still necessary, as the `BufferedReader` only has two constructors that both require `Reader`.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Bah, thank you.  I said that incorrectly.  I meant you could get rid of the line above with `DataInputStream in = ...` and pass `fstream` instead of `in`.  I did not mean to imply you should get rid of the `InputStreamReader`.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely that your number format exception is happening at this line:

```
            Integer intObj = Integer.valueOf(str);
```

See the documentation for [Integer.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) here

I'd guess this is because one of the lines is not an integer

Comment: That's the ONLY place that the exception could be thrown.  It could be something as simple as an extra empty line at the end of the file.  Putting a breakpoint (or even a println) on that line to examine the value of 'str' would ferret out the offender.

Answer (score 3):

For debugging, I think I'd recommend adding something like this line right at the beginning of your loop:

`System.out.println("str = \"" + str + "\"");`

The only place I see in that code where you'd be getting a NumberFormatException is from `Integer.valueOf`.  My guess is that you're getting some whitespace or something else into `str` and when you try to format that as a number, it's failing.

Alternately, if you want to try to catch when it's happening, you could try adding a try/catch around `Integer.valueof` like this:

```
Integer intObj = null;
try
{
     intObj = Integer.valueOf(str);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{
     System.err.println("The value \"" + str + "\" is not a number!");
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Do try to use trim() method before providing str as an argument to the valueOf() method.

```
str = str.trim();
Integer intObj = Integer.valueOf(str);
```

And Moreover, since you are using File Input/Output, why not use `java.nio` package instead of using the old `java.io` package. That `java.nio` is better for this kind of work. Do read this for [comparison b/w java.nio and java.io](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-nio-vs-io)

Hope that might help in some way.

Regards

Comment: +1 for mentioning trim. Non-printing characters in files have tripped up more file scans than I'd ever care to admit.

Comment: @Perception : I too have the same concerns :-) Thankyou and Regards